# How can get Distance left in a row

Tags: line-spacing

I want to do some Q & A. The answer is on the right horizontal line. Here is what it looks like now:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


You answer: \underline{\hbox to [some length]mm{}} ; 

My answer :  \underline{\hbox to [some length]mm{}} ;

Answer :  \underline{\hbox to [some length]mm{}} ;

Hello everyone :  \underline{\hbox to [some length]mm{}} ;

I have a idea blablablabla ： \underline{\hbox to [some length]mm{}} ;

I have an idea blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabl
ablablablabla:\underline{\hbox to [some length]mm{}} ;

I have an idea blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabl
Ablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab:\underline{\hbox to [some length]mm{}} ;

\end{document}
```

But here are the big problems:
1. The right side of the horizontal line of the answer is not aligned;
2. I don't know how much space is left on the right after filling the text on the left in a line.

I haven't searched how to get how much space is left on the right side of a line. Every time I need to manually adjust the length to achieve the following effect:
[image]

Is there a way to calculate the distance from the right-most edge of the text to the right-hand edge to achieve automatic length adjustment.

thanks！

Comment: Welcome! One out of many possible ways: `\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
You answer:& \underline{\hbox to 60mm{}} ; \\
My answer:&  \underline{\hbox to 60mm{}} ;\\
Answer:&  \underline{\hbox to 60mm{}} ;\\
Hello everyone:&  \underline{\hbox to 60mm{}} ;\\
I have a idea blablablabla:& \underline{\hbox to 60mm{}} ;
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Updated description, please look again

Comment: `Hello everyone :  \hrulefill ;` ?

Comment: Thanks , perfect solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
Hello everyone:\hrulefill ;

You answer:\hrulefill ; 

My answer:\hrulefill ;

Answer:\hrulefill ;

Hello everyone :  \hrulefill ;

I have a idea blablablabla : \hrulefill ;

I have an idea \seqsplit{blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabl}
ablablablabla:\hrulefill;

I have an idea \seqsplit{blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabl}
Ablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab:\hrulefill ;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your typesetting objective correctly, there's actually no need to know -- at least not explicitly -- how much space remains on the right-hand edge of the text block. Just use a one-column `tabularx` environment (a) whose width equals `\textwidth` and (b) whose right-hand edge gets "filled up" with `\underline{\hbox to 6cm{}}` automatically. The only constraint is that the length of the question strings on the left-hand side must not exceed `\textwidth-6cm-2\tabcolsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % optional
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\mybox{\underline{\hbox to 6cm{}}}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} % optional 
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X<{\hfill\mybox} @{}}
Your answer:     \\
My answer:       \\
Answer:          \\
Hello everyone:  \\
I have an idea blablablabla:  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used Google Translate and the meaning may not be too accurate. If  use tabularx processing, it will leave a lot of white space ( text to underline ).Updated description, please look again